# programmatically mark a shipping email as sent

Tags: email, magento, loops, magento-1.4

I have set up an observer to send out an email as soon as a tracking number is added to a shipment, but I need to be able to some how show in the admin that the email has been sent instead of displaying "the shipment email is not sent."

Here is the code I am currently using. There is an issue with it because it some how ends up sending out a ton of emails, as if it is some how stuck in a loop. I could really use some help in figuring out why this is happening.

```
class WR_TrackingEmail_Model_Observer
{
    public function sendTrackEmail($observer)
    {
        $track = $observer->getEvent()->getTrack();
        $shipment = $track->getShipment(true);
        $shipment->sendEmail();
        $shipment->setEmailSent(true);

        $saveTransaction = Mage::getModel('core/resource_transaction')
                       ->addObject($shipment)
                       ->addObject($shipment->getOrder())
                       ->save();
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you calling `sendTrackEmail` function? Is it inside a loop? Does the loop exit properly?

Comment: This is an observer that is running on the sales_order_shipment_track_save_after event. The code I provided above is the only code in the whole module, aside from the config file. I assume that there is some sort of loop happening in the last 4 lines of the code since, when I run the code without those 4 lines, only one email is sent but the "email sent" flag is not set in the db.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `save()` on the shipment object. The shipment class has an `_afterSave()` function that triggers save on the track objects. Since you are creating an observer for track_save_after, you are very likely causing a loop.

Comment: So what do I need to do, then, in order to update the "has been shipped" flag without causing a loop?

Comment: For the record, the save() is called on the $shipment object when core/resource_transaction is saved. It iterates through all added objects and saves them individually.